# retrieving host name from email address

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, email

I am trying to go through individual emails and retrieve the host name.
Each email has a To: section with an email address "`abc123@aol.com`". I'm trying to retrieve just "`aol.com`"

**Eg**:

```
To: abc123@aol.com (abc123)

To: jim@yahoo.com,hk (Jim)

To: Jim@yahoo.com\ (Jim)
```

**Expected output**:

```
aol.com

yahoo.com,hk

yahoo.com\
```

Comment: FYI http://regular-expressions.mobi/email.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed 's/.*@\(.*\) .*/\1/g' input
```

Or:

```
awk -F '[@ ]' '{print $3}' input
```

This one keeps a final space:

```
grep -Eo '@.* ' input
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU grep's perl-compatible regexes:

```
grep -oP '(?<=@)\S+'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it simple and use cut:

```
cut -d'@' -f2
```

For example, if you had these emails in one big file called emails.txt:

```
grep 'To:' emails.txt | cut -d'@' -f2
```